# Creating a loop for my encryption (Python)

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
Alpha =input ("How much would you like to add to the letter 1-10?")
Bravo =ord (input("What letter would you like to encrypt?")) + int (Alpha)
Charlie =chr (Bravo)

print(Charlie)
```

I am trying to make it so that if i choose z it will loop back to a if i shift it to  1.

Comment: Obligatory reminder that python variables are by convention camelCase, not PascalCase!

Answer (score 0):

You need the `modulo` operator, getting the index of the letter in the alphabet and then doing `(index + shift)` modulo `26` to cycle the letters avoiding an index error:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
inp = "z"
shift = 1
print(ascii_lowercase[(ascii_lowercase.index(inp) + shift) % 26])
a

inp = "w"
shift = 4
print(ascii_lowercase[(ascii_lowercase.index(inp) + shift) % 26])
a
```

To go in reverse we - shift:

```
inp = "a"
shift = 4
print(ascii_lowercase[(ascii_lowercase.index(inp) - shift) % 26])
w
```